# Where does output of print in kernel go?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, printk

I am debugging a driver for linux (specifically ubuntu server 9.04), and there are several printf statements in the code.

Where can I view the output of these statements?

EDIT1: What i'm trying to do is write to kernel using the proc file-system.
The print code is

```
static int proc_fractel_config_write(struct file *file, const char *argbuf, unsigned long count, void *data)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "writing fractel config\n");
    ...
```

In kern.log, I see the following message when i try to overwrite the file /proc/net/madwifi/ath1/fractel_config (with varying time of course).

```
[ 8671.924873] proc write 
[ 8671.924919]
```

Any explainations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the distribution, but many use `klogd(8)` to get the messages from the kernel and will either log them to a file (sometimes `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/kernel`) or to the system log via `syslog(3)`.  In the latter case, where the log entries end up will depend on the configuration of `syslogd(8)`.

One note about the `dmesg` command:  Kernel messages are stored in a circular buffer, so large amounts of output will be overwritten.

Answer (score 28):

Many times `KERN_DEBUG` level messages are filtered and you need to explicitly increase the logging level. You can see what the system defaults are by examining `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`. For example, on my system:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4       4       1       7
```

the first number shows the console log level is `KERN_WARNING` (see [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man pages for more information). This means `KERN_NOTICE`, `KERN_INFO`, and `KERN_DEBUG` messages will be filtered from the console. To increase the logging level or verbosity, use `dmesg`

```
$ sudo dmesg -n 7
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7       4       1       7
```

Here, setting the level to 7 (`KERN_DEBUG`) will allow all levels of messages to appear on the console. To automate this, add `loglevel=`*N* to the kernel boot parameters where N is the log level you want going to the console or `ignore_loglevel` to print all kernel messages to the console.

Comment: Log level constants are currently (since 3.6?) defined in [<linux/kern_levels.h>](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kern_levels.h)

Answer (score 6):

You'll get the output with the command `dmesg`

Comment: Can't find what I am looking for, but I will try again.

Comment: Are they really "printf" statements? They really should be "printk", I don't think printf is defined in the kernel (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: It is my understanding that chris is correct. printk() will output to dmesg or /var/log/messages

Answer (score 5):

**dmesg** outputs all the messages from the kernel. Finding your desired messages would be difficult. Better use **dmesg** and **grep** combination and use a driver specific label in all your `printk` messages. That will ease in eliminating all the unwanted messages.

```
printk("test: hello world")

dmesg | grep test
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 11.10 and 10.04 LTS, on the former I edited /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, then restarted rsyslog using "sudo service rsyslog restart"  to restart rsyslogd. Then it worked.

Note that Ubuntu uses **r**syslogd, not syslogd.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a higher level than KERN_DEBUG, for example KERN_INFO.  Depending on your configuration the lowest priority messages might not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In centos (Atleast in centos 6.6) the output will be in /var/log/messages