# Kernel module with included local sources

Tags: kernel, header-files

Say I have the following structure:

```
.\
 |_ foo.c
 |_ inc\
     |_ foo_helper.c
     |_ foo_helper.h
```

I want to obtain foo.ko. foo.c should `#include <foo_helper.h>`. Also, a debug message with `printk` is placed in the foo.c init function, just to see if the function was loaded.
My Kbuild file is:

```
obj-m := foo.o
foo-y := inc/foo_helper.o

ccflags-y := -I$(src)/inc/
```

Compiles fine. `insmod` returns `0`; `lsmod` lists the module as loaded, but the debug message is not printed in kern.log.

### A minimal example:

- foo.c:

> ```
> #undef __KERNEL__
> #define __KERNEL__
> #undef MODULE
> #define MODULE
>
> #include <linux/module.h>   // included for all kernel modules
> #include <linux/kernel.h>   // included for KERN_INFO
>
> #include <foo_helper.h>
>
> static int __init foo_init(void)
> {
>     printk(KERN_INFO "Foo inserted successfully.\n");
>
>     foo_help_me();
>
>     return 0;
> }
>
> static void __exit foo_exit(void){}
> module_init(foo_init);
> module_exit(foo_exit);
> MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
> MODULE_AUTHOR("Foo");
> MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Bar");
> ```

- inc/foo_helper.h:

> ```
> #ifndef __FOO_CUSTOM_HELPER
> #define __FOO_CUSTOM_HELPER
>
> #include <linux/kernel.h>
>
> void foo_help_me(void);
>
> #endif  /* __FOO_CUSTOM_HELPER */
> ```

- inc/foo_helper.c:

> ```
> #include "foo_helper.h"
>
> void foo_help_me(void)
> {
>   printk(KERN_INFO "We're inside the helper, seems to be working.\n");
> }
> ```

- Kbuild:

> ```
> obj-m := foo.o
> foo-y := inc/foo_helper.o
> ccflags-y := -I$(src)/inc
> ```

- Makefile:

> ```
> ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
> include Kbuild
> else
> KDIR := /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
> default:
>   $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules
> endif
> ```

Comment: If removing KERN_INFO fixes the problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4520973/26683

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. printk() works fine if the foo_helper.* dependency is cut out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the meantime at: [tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x351.html). The only modifications needed are in the Kbuild file, as follows:

> ```
> obj-m := fool.o
> fool-objs := foo.o inc/foo_helper.o
> ccflags-y := -I$(src)/inc/
> ```

So I'll need to link the two *intermediary* objects (foo and foo_helper) in order to obtain a third, final one, in this case I called it **fool**.