# Proc file to enable or disable the dmesg or printk statements

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I want to write a proc file by which i can enable or disable the printk msg printed on the console.Or there will be something like all the printk messages will be printed in my proc file.Then I will be able to read those **printk messages in my proc file**. How to do this all.Please give me some advise.

Thanks

Baldev Singh

Comment: How abt `cat proc/kmsg` to read all log messages ?

Comment: Check if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518420/where-does-output-of-print-in-kernel-go) will be helpful

Comment: thanks.. This link is helpfull for me..

Comment: But my requirement is like this :-
I have a large file and i have added lots of printk messages in that file.So at the time of execution of that file,i will get all the printk messages.
What i want is if I want to print these messages then enable it otherwise disable it.
Because i am writing programs in kernel space,so i want a proc file to do this.