# How can I get strings which are located at a specific virtual address in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, kmalloc

I have a pointer to an array with symbols.

```
char *myArr = kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL); //put message in kernel
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    myArr[i] = x30; //put symbols here
    }
printk(KERN_INFO "The string is located at virtual address %p, physical address %lx\n", myArr, __pa(myArr));
```

I compiled this module with make and uploaded this module using the command:

```
sudo insmod ./my_module.ko
```

How can I read this string when this module is in kernel? 
Do I have to use some specific programs?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518420/where-does-output-of-print-in-kernel-go

Comment: dmesg, syslog, klog.. there is plenty of built-in tools in linux you can use.